# Network monitor program

Tags: network-monitoring

Is there network monitor program for windows servers can keep tracking throughput, pkt transmitted/received/discard/re-transmitted BY TIME? I am trying to find the reason causing my server network instability. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out the networking performance counters within the **[Windows Performance Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749249.aspx)** (Perfmon.exe). You can launch this from the Administrative Tools in Windows Server 2003.

You can also configure it to save your logging data on your file system, or in a database.

Answer (score 0):

A great network monitoring program is [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/), which probably has everything you need.

Comment: Actually wireshark does not allow you to monitor your network, it's more for tracking all the network packets.
Perfmon.exe gives betters regarding the load of you nic, the average speed, etc...